# Nightly build error caused by PostSharp 2.0 : Connection unexpectly closed by the server

Tags: .net, postsharp

We're experiencing nightly build errors caused by PostSharp, version 2. The error is :

```
Pipe error on the client: PostSharp.Pipe.PipeException: GetOverlappedResult failed Error 109.
at PostSharp.Pipe.PipeStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) 
at System.IO.Stream.ReadByte() 
at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte()
at PostSharp.Pipe.PipePacket.Read(BinaryReader reader) 
at PostSharp.Pipe.PipeEndpoint.ReadPacket() 
at PostSharp.MSBuild.PostSharp20.ExecutePipeClient().
```

PostSharp.targets(353,5): error : Connection unexpectly closed by the server.

The targets file looks like this :

```
<PostSharp20    Project="$(PostSharp20Project)"
                            Input="$(_PostSharp20InputBin)"
                            Properties="$(PostSharpProperties)"
                            AttachDebugger="$(PostSharpAttachDebugger)"
                            ClientAttachDebugger="$(PostSharpClientAttachDebugger)"
                            TraceCategories="$(PostSharpTrace)"
                            DisableReflection="$(PostSharpDisableReflection)"
                            Host="$(PostSharpHost)"
                            TargetPlatform="$(PostSharpTargetPlatform)"
                            NoLogo="true"
                            ExpectedMessages="$(PostSharpExpectedMessages)"
                            IgnoreError="$(PostSharpIgnoreError)"
                            FailOnUnexpectedMessage="$(PostSharpFailOnUnexpectedMessage)"
                            LicenseKey="$(PostSharpLicenseKey)"
                >
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="PostSharpExitCode"/>
</PostSharp20>
```

In the csproj we're having the following lines:

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <UsePostSharp>true</UsePostSharp>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <Import Project="$(ProjectDir)..\..\LibBin\PostSharp\Tool\PostSharp.targets" />
```

The version of the .NET project is 4.0, VS is 2013 on Windows Server 2008 R2. I know one option is to upgrade to version 4, but we cannot do that, for the moment.

Comment: It must be caused by PostSharp pipe server shutting down due to some exception that we can't see here. Please, try to set the MSBuild property `PostSharpHost` to `Native` and rebuild the project. This should display an original error that causes the crash of the pipe server.

Comment: I just saw that we have the property set to Native :<PostSharpHost Condition="'$(PostSharpHost)'=='' AND '$(PostSharpUsePipeServer)'=='False'">Native</PostSharpHost>

Comment: Hm, this is strange, because the error message is about connection to pipe server. So, you set PostSharpUsePipeServer to False? You can check the real values of properties during build by enabling diagnostic MSBuild output (Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run).

Comment: Found the issue : the build server had a memory allocation issue (the memory on server was only 512 M of RAM, it's a VM)